# Segmentation fault when my array is bigger than 4 elements

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    int k, i, j, n, smallest;
    int numbers[k];
    printf("Introduceti k: ");
    scanf("%d", &k);
    for (i = 0; i < k; i = i + 1)
    {
        printf("Introduceti %d numar: ", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &n);
        numbers[i] = n;
    }
    printf("%d", numbers[k-1]);
    return 0;
}
```

When I set the `k` value to be less than 5, the program executes well, but when I set it to be >=5 it gives the error:

`zsh: segmentation fault  ./main.out`

P.S. I'm using MacOS BigSur 11.6

Comment: `k` is uninitialized when you define the array `numbers`.  Define the array when you know how big it should be— after the `scanf`.  You should check that call succeeded and that the entered value is not too big.

Comment: but why does it work when k < 4? What value is considered too big?

Comment: It “works” by accident.  On Windows systems, there is usually a limit of 1MiB for the total stack size, so a limit of about 250k would be reasonable.  You might reasonably impose a lower limit; no-one is going to type anything like that much data.  Also, don’t forget to eliminate zero and negative array sizes.

Answer (score 0):

With `int numbers[k];`, you are setting aside space in the stack for `k` integers. But, in your program, `k` is uninitialized at this point and you are setting aside space for whatever happens to be the value of `k` times the size of an `int`. Technically, this is [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and your program might do anything (including doing nothing, crashing  and working perfectly).

You should do `scanf("%d", &k);` before you declare the `numbers` array.

EDIT - Since you need to keep declarations at the top, you may use `malloc()`:

```
int main() 
{
    int k, i, j, n, smallest;
    int *numbers;
    printf("Introduceti k: ");
    scanf("%d", &k);
    numbers = malloc(k * sizeof (int));
```

`malloc()` will allocate space for `k` integers on the heap. Do not forget to call `free(numbers)` once you are done with the `numbers` variable.

Comment: I would gladly do that, but my teacher told me that I can only declare my variables on top of the program, because it is the right way to do it in C

Comment: @YourLogarithm, how old is your teacher?? Please get him fired (or a mandatory refresh course ;p). Declaring variables on top of the program was the only way to do it in the first version of C (K&R C). However, since 1999 (C99) this is not necessary anymore and considered a bad habit! It's a good practice to define variables when you need them.

Comment: @YourLogarithm Does your teacher generally restrict you to C89? Since C99 it has been allowed to intermingle declarations and code. Variable length arrays (as in `int numbers[k];`) was also introduced as C99 (and subsequently turned into an optional feature in C11).

Comment: Well he just told us that variables in C are declared on top and we should do like that, there was no talking about C89 and C99.